# How to set pandas Dataframe column name as headers?

Tags: python, pandas

I created a Dataframe with the below code.

```
>>>in:    df_final = pandas.DataFrame(combined_data, columns=['Item', aa, bb, cc, dd])

>>>out:
                         Item     FY2012     FY2013     FY2014    FY2015
0               Total Revenue    654.766     535.79    321.394   445.241   
1                Gross Profit    256.776    268.412     156.47   220.687   
2                  Net Income     60.994     44.026     57.469    41.273   
3                      EBITDA    111.324    110.268   (41.478)    83.382
```

However, when I try to transpose the code by adding a `.T`, I get:

```
>>>in:    df_final = pandas.DataFrame(combined_data, columns=['Item', aa, bb, cc, dd]).T

>>>>out:    
                       0             1           2         3
Item            Total Revenue  Gross Profit  Net Income    EBITDA   
FY2012                654.766       256.776      60.994   111.324   
FY2013                 535.79       268.412      44.026   110.268   
FY2014                321.394        156.47      57.469  (41.478)   
FY2015                445.241       220.687      41.273    83.382
```

After `Transposing`, what should I do so that instead of having  `[0, 1, 2, 3]` as the headers, I make `Total Revenue  Gross Profit  Net Income    EBITDA` as the headers instead?

IE: If I did not `Transpose` the Dataframe, `print(df.columns.values)` would give me `Item     FY2012     FY2013     FY2014    FY2015` as the headers. But after `Transposing` the Dataframe, `[0, 1, 2, 3]` became the headers, instead of `Total Revenue  Gross Profit  Net Income    EBITDA`

Comment: Could you provide a sample input with the expected output?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by row labels? The entries in the `Item` column, perhaps? If so, you can obtain a `Series` object containing the elements of that column as `df['Item']`, where `df` is your `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Item column as index so it becomes 'columns' when you transpose it:

```
df.set_index('Item').T
Out: 
Item    Total Revenue  Gross Profit  Net Income   EBITDA
FY2012        654.766       256.776      60.994  111.324
FY2013        535.790       268.412      44.026  110.268
FY2014        321.394       156.470      57.469  -41.478
FY2015        445.241       220.687      41.273   83.382
```